# How to visible indicator on busy

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am trying to do the front end XAML code in C#. When I try to bind the `activity indicator` with `IsBusy` Am not able to achieve it.

I want the activity indicator to pop up when the page is busy.

Comment: Make this an answer to the original question, otherwise people will try to answer your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is to Show How can we achieve a basic screen with **scrollview** and a **indicator** in backend C# code.

the **Layout** assigned to the **scroll Content** is any basic layout which we design as per the requirement.

Here is my code sample:

```
#region render
scroll = new ScrollView
{
    Content = layout
};
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(scroll, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(scroll, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

AbsoluteLayout screenMask = new AbsoluteLayout { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#22000000") };
screenMask.BindingContext = this;
screenMask.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy", BindingMode.OneWay);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(screenMask, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(screenMask, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

ActivityIndicator indicator = new ActivityIndicator { Color = Color.Black };
indicator.BindingContext = this;
indicator.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy",BindingMode.OneWay);
indicator.SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsRunningProperty, "IsBusy");
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(indicator, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(indicator, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

Content = new AbsoluteLayout
{
    Children = { scroll, screenMask, indicator }
};
#endregion
```

Hope this helps many people.